# How can I submit ASP,NET MVC listbox selections outside of the html form?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a basic ASP.NET MVC3 view like this:

```
@Html.Label("Administrative Options");

    <br />

    @Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.SelectedUsers, Model.Users)

    <br />

    using (Html.BeginForm("AssignAdmins", "Account"))
    {

    <div id="MakeAdminsbtn">
        <input id="MakeAdmins" type="submit" value="Assign Administrators" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to Admin?');" />
    </div> 
    }

    <br />

    using (Html.BeginForm("RevokeAdmins", "Account"))
    {

    <div id="RemAdminsbtn">
        <input id="RemAdmins" type="submit" value="Revoke Administrators" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to De-Admin?');" />
    </div> 
    }

    <br />

    using (Html.BeginForm("DeleteAccounts", "Account"))
    {

    <div id="DelAcctbtn">
        <input id="DelAcct" type="submit" value="Delete Accounts" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to Delete?');" />
    </div> 
    }
```

Each button is in it's own form because I think that's what I have to do in order to submit to different actions?

The problem I'm having is that the returned model does not contain the `SelectedUsers` from the `ListBoxFor` unless that statement is inside the form used by the submit button.

How can I get the model appropriately populated with the selected users for each of the given submit options while only displaying a single ListBox?

Comment: You would need to use some javascript to get exactly what you want in the question.  However, if you put names on the buttons you could use a single controller that had a variable for each button name and use that to decide the action.  Do you prefer a no javascript solution?

Comment: @BryanRoberts I prefer no js, it seems the only way is with a `switch` on my controller as per Dave Findley's blog here: http://weblogs.asp.net/dfindley/archive/2009/05/31/asp-net-mvc-multiple-buttons-in-the-same-form.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use only one ActionMethod and there base on witch button is clicked to call that action that you nead example:

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home"))
    {

<div>
@Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.SelectedUsers, Model.Users)

    <input id="MakeAdmins" type="submit" name="btnSubmit" value="Assign Administrators" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to Admin?');" />
    <input id="RemAdmins" type="submit" name="btnSubmit" value="Revoke Administrators" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to De-Admin?');" />
    <input id="DelAcct" type="submit" name="btnSubmit" value="Delete Accounts" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to Delete?');" />
</div> 
    }
```

and then in your controller

```
   [HttpPost]
            public ActionResult Index(string btnSubmit, FormCollection collection)
            {
//btnSubmit this is the button that is clicked.
                return View();
            }
```

Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: +1 this is a common no-script solution, as explained by Dave Findley's blog here: http://weblogs.asp.net/dfindley/archive/2009/05/31/asp-net-mvc-multiple-buttons-in-the-same-form.aspx

Comment: `@Html.ListBoxFor` is not in my suggestions list. If I type as `@Html.ListBoxFor` , it shows an error as "Html helper doesn't contain a definition for ListBoxFor..." What is the reason for that...?